# Creating a Sequence of Weeks between two dates by counting each Friday

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle-SQL to accomplish this however.

An example is easiest be easiest to explain, Let's say I have a job_id (27) that starts Feb-1-2023 (Wednesday) and ends March-1-2023 (also Wednesday). All of these columns, id, start_date, end_date, exist in the same table.

### The table would look something like:

| Job_id | Seq# | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27 | 1 | Feb-3-2023 |
| 27 | 2 | Feb-10-2023 |
| 27 | 3 | Feb-17-2023 |
| 27 | 4 | Feb-24-2023 |
| 27 | 5 | Mar-3-2023 |

Of course this would need to be done for all job_id's in the jobs table.

The purpose of this is to create a Gaussian bell curve of hours worked, given an expected peak_time and std. dev. This way I will be able to have a slight forecasting simulator.

But for now I need this query to accomplish this! Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I was able to find the first Friday after the Start_date with this query,

```
SELECT start_date, NEXT_DAY(start_date - 1, 'FRIDAY') AS first_friday
FROM JOBS;
```

as a starting point,

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: For a start, review https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-generate-days-weeks-or-months-between-two-dates-in-oracle-database#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20this%20to%20fetch%20all%20the,row%20number%20%28minus%20one%29%20to%20the%20start%20date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (job_id, start_date, end_date) as
  2    (select 27, date '2023-02-01', date '2023-03-01' from dual union all
  3     select 30, date '2023-02-06', date '2023-02-25' from dual
  4    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  5  select job_id,
  6    column_value as seq#,
  7    next_day(start_date -1 , 'FRIDAY') + ((column_value - 1) * 7) as datum
  8  from test cross join
  9    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                        connect by level <= (end_date - start_date) / 7 + 1
 11                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 12  order by job_id, seq#;

    JOB_ID       SEQ# DATUM
---------- ---------- -----------
        27          1 Feb-03-2023
        27          2 Feb-10-2023
        27          3 Feb-17-2023
        27          4 Feb-24-2023
        27          5 Mar-03-2023
        30          1 Feb-10-2023
        30          2 Feb-17-2023
        30          3 Feb-24-2023

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```